# temp pip install error no such file or directory

Tags: python, pip, installation

I'm trying to install a Python package I downloaded from GitHub, but when I do so I get the following:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install C:\Python27\GetOldTweets-python- 
master.zip
Processing c:\python27\getoldtweets-python-master.zip
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\andres\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-req-build-cn4z5x\\setup.py'
----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\andres\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-cn4z5x\
```

I guess it's something about the zip file decompression creating temp files, but why is it not accessible to Python / does not exist?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Does the zip contain `setup.py` at the top-level? I suspect there is a top-level subdirectory that prevents the zip to be pip-installable.

Comment: No, it does not. It contains no setup.py at all.

Comment: *no `setup.py` at all* — then it's also not a pip-installable source package.